# Password verify always returning true

Tags: php, encryption, authentication, mysqli, passwords

I've been trying to write a simple login for a couple of days now. After I'd thought I had it working, I realized that it would accept any input in the password field as being true so I scrapped it and started again. I'm trying to use the php function `password_verify` for the verification but no matter what I do, it always returns true still. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Here is my code (I know it's not secure, I just want it to recognize a wrong password for now)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $hash))
    {
        echo 0;
    }
    else
    {
         echo 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @FerozAkbar It is in the [PHP core](http://php.net/password_verify).

Comment: the one that you're comparing should be a fetched hashed password from the db row that was registered in a previous operation.

Comment: Is that your "full" code? I doubt it since you tagged this as `mysqli`. Show us how you're using it. I have a few ready-to-go scripts that use both functions.

Comment: password entered, select from table, query, fetch array, if password matches in row using `password_verify()`, done. Those are the basic steps.

Comment: You shouldn't be hashing the input password, but comparing it with the already inserted password that was hashed at the time of insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are `$password` getting a  `$_POST['password'];`

You are  `hash` a `$password` which is `$_POST['password'];`

```
 password_verify($_POST['password'], $hash)
```

You are comparing a `$_POST['password']` with a `hash`. the `hash` is also `$_POST['password']`.

That's why they return always true.because the `$passwod`,`hash` are `$_POST['password']` is same.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now!

Answer (score 2):

The reason it always returns true is because you are verifying a hash that you just created... it will always be verified correctly.

When you use the `password_verify()` function the `$hash` parameter has to come from somewhere else (usually a database of some kind).

```
// If this is a POST request then handle the form
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    // Get password from form
    $pass = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);

    // Connect to a database of some kind
    // Get a previously hashed password
    $hash = 'A HASH FROM SOMEWHERE ELSE...';

    // Verify the previously hashed password
    // against the password provided by the user
    if (password_verify($pass, $hash)) {
        echo 'Password is valid!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You check the post password with the post password. You should check the post password instead with a wanted password.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `$hash` to the password you received through POST.

This is how `password_verify` works

`boolean password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )`

Verifies that the given `$hash` matches the password received.

So now you're checking the password stored in `$hash` with the password obtained in POST which are the same.

Hence always true.